# divide group data base on select columns values?

Tags: python, pandas

**df**

```
   ts_code    type  close

  0 861001.TI   1   648.399
  1 861001.TI   20  588.574
  2 861001.TI   30  621.926
  3 861001.TI   60  760.623
  4 861001.TI   90  682.313
  ...   ... ... ...
  8328  885933.TI   5   1083.141
  8329  885934.TI   1   951.493
  8330  885934.TI   5   1011.346
  8331  885935.TI   1   1086.558
  8332  885935.TI   5   1028.449
```

**Goal**

```
ts_code    l5d_close l20d_close …… l90d_close
861001.TI   NaN       1.10          0.95
……           ……       ……            ……
```

I want to groupby `ts_code` to calculate the `close` of `type(1)`/the `close` of `type(N:5,20,30……)`. Take `861001.TI` for example, `l5d_close` is nan because there is no value when the type is 5. `l20d_close` equals 648.399/588.574=1.10, `l90d_close` equals 648.399/682.313=0.95. And the result is rounded.

Try

```
df.groupby('ts_code')\
  .pipe(lambda x: x[x.type==1].close/x[x.type==10].close)

Got: KeyError: 'Column not found: False'
```

The type values is: 1,5,20,30,60,90,180,200

Notice: There is one value of `type` columns for each `ts_code`

Comment: How are the values `10.1` and `5.2` calculated in your example output? They don't seem to match the intended ratio formula in the code attempt

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Sorry, I update it.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding the desired logic. Could you show exactly how the numbers in the example input mathematically combine to give the numbers 10.1, and 5.2?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler Sorry, I update my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to make sure `type == 1` is the first row per group and extract them with [`groupby.transform('first')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['ts_code', 'type'])
close1 = df.groupby('ts_code')['close'].transform('first')
df['close'] = close1 / df['close']

#         ts_code  type     close
# 0     861001.TI     1  1.000000
# 1     861001.TI    20  1.101644
# 2     861001.TI    30  1.042566
# 3     861001.TI    60  0.852458
# ...         ...   ...       ...
```

Then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) the `type` column into column headers:

```
out = (df.pivot(index='ts_code', columns='type', values='close')
         .drop(columns=1)
         .add_prefix('l')
         .add_suffix('d_close'))

# type       l5d_close  l20d_close  l30d_close  l60d_close  l90d_close
# ts_code
# 861001.TI        NaN    1.101644    1.042566    0.852458    0.950296
# ...              ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
```

---

To chain together, [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) a `ratio` column before the [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
(df.assign(ratio=df.groupby('ts_code').close.transform('first').div(df.close))
   .pivot(index='ts_code', columns='type', values='ratio')
   .drop(columns=1)
   .add_prefix('l')
   .add_suffix('d_close'))

# type       l5d_close  l20d_close  l30d_close  l60d_close  l90d_close
# ts_code
# 861001.TI        NaN    1.101644    1.042566    0.852458    0.950296
# ...              ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
```

Comment: greate, but could you merge all code into chain method?

Comment: @Jack i updated with a chained version (using [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html))

Answer (score 1):

well, I don't think you need group by here as you aren't really grouping or using any aggregative function.
I think it will be easier to just create a new DF using a function

```
ts_codes = df.ts_code.unique()
types = [5,20,30,60,90,180,200]
ts_results = []
for ts_code in ts_codes:
    ts_result = [ts_code]
    temp = df.loc[df.tscode == ts_code]
    val_1 = temp.loc[df.type == 1]['close'].iloc[0] # to get the actual value 
    for type in types:
        val = temp.loc[df.type == type]
        if len(val) > 0:
            ts_result.append(val_1/val)
        else:
            ts_result.append(None)
    ts_results.append(ts_result)
results_df = pd.DataFrame(ts_results,coluns=['ts_code','l5d_close', 'l20d_close' …… 'l90d_close']
```

I didn't run the code to get the results as you didn't provide an easy way to generate your data hope this help

and sorry but sometimes the easy solution is the best (I would have move it to a function)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table()` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)). As long as there's *some* data of each `type`, that column will be created.

```
pivoted = (
    df.pivot_table(values=["close"], index="ts_code", columns="type")
    # get rid of the first MultiIndex level
    .droplevel(0, axis=1)
    # divide type == 1 column values by every other column
    .pipe(lambda f: f[[1]].values / f.iloc[:, 1:])
    .round(2)
)

# format column names
pivoted.columns = "l" + pivoted.columns.astype(str) + "d_close"
pivoted
```

This returns:

```
type       l5d_close  l20d_close  l30d_close  l60d_close  l90d_close
ts_code                                                             
861001.TI        NaN    1.101644    1.042566    0.852458    0.950296
885933.TI        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
885934.TI   0.940818         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
885935.TI   1.056502         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def get_sum_by_type(ts_code,type):
    num = df.query(f"ts_code=='{ts_code}' and type==1")['close'].sum()
    den = df.query(f"ts_code=='{ts_code}' and type=={type}")['close'].sum()
    return 

types = [5,20,30,60,90,180,200]
results = []
for tscode, type in zip(df.ts_code.uniques(), types):
    template = dict(ts_code=tscode)
    template.update({
        f"l{type_}d_close": get_sum_by_type(tscode, type ) for type_ in types
    })
    results.append(template)
goal = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

The only thing I see in the code is that you will need to replace the zeros for nan, because when there are no type_1 for a given ts_0, the function `get_sum_by_type` will return 0 due the `num` will be 0. You can manage the `0/0` operations inside `get_sum_by_type` if there are no `close` for a given `ts_code` and `type`